# Set column title in infragistics datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics

How do i change the name of a column with C#? The datagrid is being populated with a Dictionary, and it defaults the title to be Value.

Cheers

Comment: Can you provide more information about your problem please. Post code if you can. Again, please refer Infragistics community forum for specific results.

Comment: OK, so basically i have my datagrid with datasource set to the key values of a dictionary. But the column header of the grid is set to value. However i want to to be changed to something else. And it needs to be done in C#, but there doesnt see to be anything like datagrid.columnName = "foo"

Comment: The way we set header text of a infragistics grid's column is by accessing its fields collection.... like this... `myXamDataGrid.FieldLayouts[0].Fields[0].Name = "Header1"`... does this guide you in correct direction?

Comment: This does exactly what i need, however, it seems to remove all the text from the fields after it? So after i attach it to the datasource (a dictionary) the title is correct but all the values have no text. (Still selectable mind you)

Code is there fore like this...


            Processes.DataSource = Dict.Keys;
            Processes.FieldLayouts[0].Fields[0].Name = _envSel;

Comment: My bad! The setting should be `myXamDataGrid.FieldLayouts[0].Fields[0].Label = "Header1"` and the `Name` property must be the PropertyName from individual object represented by a `Key`.... e.g. if your dictionary `Key` is of type `Employee` class, then `myXamDataGrid.FieldLayouts[0].Fields[0].Label = "Employee Name"` and `myXamDataGrid.FieldLayouts[0].Fields[0].Name = "EmpName"`... let me know if this helps.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what i wanted :D Cheeeers!

Answer (score 8):

```
foreach (Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridColumn column in e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns)
{
    if(NamesEqual(column.Key, "ID"))
    {
        column.Header.Caption = "MyNewColumnName";
    }
}
```

Comment: tsells this is not Windows Infragistics but WPF.

Comment: It's actually WinForms not Windows - but thanks anyway for the downvote.